# TCP-connection is killed if running the applications on the remote server-machine - weird behaviour

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

So, I know this question will be a bit "fuzzy", as I cannot really give you any code examples of the issue, but I will give it a try to explain the problem and maybe someone recognizes it.

Basically, I have two applications, both written in C#.

[App A] connects to [App B] via a TCP-socket and sends data, and [App B] can of course send data back to [App A] on that same TCP-connection. [App B] is an app that has been in use for 6-7 years and is working well on the "production server".

The problem is this:

If I run [App A] and [App B] on my local machine, the comm. between them works just as expected.

But if I run [App A] and [App B] on the server/remote machine (both are running on the same machine, but on the remote server instead) then the communication between them does not work as expected. Then [App A] connects and manages to send data to [App B], and [App B] reacts accordingly and send the reply to [App A], but the reply is never received at [App A], instead I see that the TCP-connection is killed.

This does *not* happen if I run the exact same code on my local machine.

Now, if I instead run [App A] on my local machone, and [App A] connects to [App B] on the remote/server machine, then it also works as expected, ie. the comm. works and TCP-connection stays alive.

If I then let [App B] continue to run on the remote server, but instead start [App A] on the remote server (instead of my local machine), then it does not work again; the TCP-connection is killed after [App A] has sent its data.

As I see it, this is not a problem with the code, as it works locally and also if I run the apps on different machines, right?

I am running Windows on both machine, Win 7 locally and Win Server 2003 on the remote/server machine, using .NET 4.0.

Does this ring any bells?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very much like the server running App A has a local firewall setting or a physical firewall preventing the inbound connection from App B's server.

Check that inbound connections are allowed for the port you are listening on, for the connection type (TCP or UDP).

Comment: It cant be that, since [App A] manages to establish a connection to [App B] and also manages to send data to [App B]... And they are both running locally on the server, to the firewall does not block anything.

Comment: @Ted: There can be separate firewall rules controlling outbound and inbound traffic.  Also, do you have bidirectional communication on a single port, or one port for each direction?

Comment: Bidirectional, one port. I have to reiterate that this works normally, without problems. [App B] ahs been running for 6 years, and is still running "fault free", but then there other connections to it (not [App A]). But it doesnt make sense, as it works locally, and if I move [App A] to my local machine...

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark as there isn't much to go on. My random guess would be that one of the ports used by App A or App B is in use on the server/remote machine. The same port may be freely available on your local machine so you don't observe the same behavior.

Comment: [App B] listens to a specific port, and that port is free for sure (I can connect to [App B] as I normally do). [App A], that is running locally on the remote server can connect to [App B] and also send data to it, but connection is killed thereafter...

Comment: My point is that it is not an issue with a port being blocked, as [App B] starts up and I can connect to it via telnet (both locally and remotly). [App A] can also connect to it, and also send data but then the connection is killed =(

Comment: @Ted - Have you tried working out why the connection is being killed. Look for specific TCP packets using wireshark.

Comment: I have of course made logs in the code just before and after the data that I am expecting back is sent, and the connection seems to be open and valid after the line where the sending takes place. Also, please note that the *exact same code* works locally on my computer, and also if I move [App A] to another computer, and not have them both on the remote machine....

Comment: @Ted - I meant TCP packets such as ACK, SYN, RST. You wont see these in code, you need to look at the wire format using an application such as wireshark.

Comment: Mm, I know. I havent looked at it yet, but Im sure that SYN etc is sent to close the sockets, question is why. I will look at it too.

Comment: I tried to use Wireshark, but I cannot capture the data I am looking for. Seems I cannot get the right filters there... hmm.

Comment: Ok, I cannot capture traffic using Wireshark if it is just communication within the same server: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback